# Do I need a NIC to be installed in my computer in order to use a GPRS modem?

Tags: networking, lan, modem, network-adapter

Modern motherboards come with a built-in LAN controller.

What happens when I am using a GPRS modem - does it involves the usage of that LAN controller in any way?

Comment: If somebody could explain the procedure a little bit ?

Comment: Do you have any make/model of GPRS modem in mind? If so, the interface specs can be checked.

Comment: @Linker3000 Modem uses USB interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the GPRS Modem in question!

If it is a GPRS card modem for a laptop (Express Card/similar) or desktop(PCI Express), the answer will be no.

If it is a GPRS Modem that has only a network card port, the answer will obviously be yes.

Comment: ..and the last GPRS/GSM modems I used had serial port interfaces

Comment: @William Hilsum I think i was not able to explain the question properly.  What i wanted to ask was,  what happens when a GPRS modem retrieves some data from the internet , does it gets processed by the processor directly or NIC has any role to play in it ?

Comment: Depends entirely on the device. Is it a software based card (in which case, the pc will do nearly all the work) - is it a hardware based card (in which case, the computer will do a lot less), is it a modem, in which case it will do all the processing and just pass on the ethernet traffic.

Comment: @William Hilsum Its a CDMA  Modem, with USB interface.